# If I claim Facebook page usernames do they auto redirect from old URL?

Tags: facebook

My Facebook page currently has the URL https://www.facebook.com/pages/sitenamecom/129112207588. 
I want to claim my username so it will become https://www.facebook.com/sitename.
My question is do existing links to the old URL automatically redirect to the new one. I have links in a lot of places and will change over time but in case I miss some will they automatically go to the new page URL or will there be an error.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a Facebook support site.

Comment: Apologies it seemed by best option after lots of searching.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is do existing links to the old URL automatically redirect to the new one.

Yes, they will.

I don’t know if this is explicitly documented somewhere, but from personal experience I can say that there have been no problems so far with the “old” addresses of pages still being used once a page name has been set.

Users clicking on an old link will be redirected to the new address, and f.e. like buttons pointing to the “old” page address will display and count likes for the “new” address automatically (since they are basically both referring to the same object).